# What does context mean in the terms of Loopback 4

Tags: loopback4

In loopback 4 there is a concept named context what does that mean. What is the use of context and what can be a practical explanation for the context.
Thank you

Comment: This is an [official example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/examples/context) of `Context` that might help you understand.

Comment: Thanks @ZhikaiXiong but I wanted to know if someone can define the meaning of context in their own words, it would be really helpful.
Thanks for reply

Answer (score 3):

A `Context` is a basic `loopback4` concept and is a global or local registry of `configs`, `states`, `dependencies`, `classes`, `factories`, `services`, etc.

Think about of a `key-value-store` which can be accessed and used by different components. The `key` is called [`Binding`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Binding.html) and the value can be anything / everything of above.

The [`Context`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Context.html) concept goes hand-in-hand with other concepts like [`dependency injection`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Dependency-injection.html), which uses the `Context` to lookup [`components`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Components.html).

The [official documentation describes `Context`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Context.html) this way:

> #### What is Context?
>
> - An abstraction of all state and dependencies in your application LoopBack uses context to manage everything
> - A global registry for anything/everything in your app (all configs, state, dependencies, classes, etc)
> - An inversion of control container used to inject dependencies into your code